# tinymce and jquery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using tinymce and simple modal (jquery plugin). Initially, it was not worked (meaning I cannot type in the textarea) for the second or more opening modal dialog unless I refreshed the page. Now I changed my code and now I could type but the problem persist is the submit button doesn't work anymore. I tried to trace in firebug and I found some errors like this

Thanks in advance

Permission denied to get property XULElement.accessibleType
[Break on this error] var tinymce={majorVersion:"3",minorVersi...hanged();return true}return false})})();

here is the revised code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.basic').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();     
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal({onShow: function (dialog) {
            tinyMCE.init({
                // General options
                mode : "textareas",
                theme : "advanced",
                setup : function (ed) {
                    ed.onKeyPress.add(
                        function (ed, evt) {
                            var y =  tinyMCE.get('test').getContent();
                            $('#rem_char').html(100 - y.length);
                            if (y.length == 100){
                                //ed.getWin().document.body.innerHTML = y.substring(0,100);
                                alert("Your element has exceeded the 100 character limit. If you add anymore text it may be truncated when saved.")
                                return; 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },          
                plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount",

                // Theme options
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "fontselect,fontsizeselect,bullist,numlist,forecolor,backcolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",       
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                dialog_type : "modal"
            }); 
            return false;
        }});
    });
    $('.close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.modal.close();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your HTML page and all Javascripts called from the *same* domain? (domain.com and www.domain.com are *different* domains).

Comment: hi pekka,

Yes, I am using the same domain.

Thanks

Comment: hi to all

I found out that there is a conflict with tinymce and jquery plugin validatation. I tried to remove validate then it works fine.

Any thought or suggestion the problem?

here is my validation code

   $("#create_school").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorElement: "span",   
    success: function(span) {
     span.text("ok!");
    },        
    rules: {
     name: {
      required:true,
      minlength:5,
     },
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
     var y =  tinyMCE.get('test').getContent();
     alert(y.length);   
     alert("Submitted!");
    }   
   });